# Minimum interval such that $X\%$ of intervals will contain $\ge Y$ events

Tags: algorithms, point-process, interarrival-time

I have a data set that contains the dates and times of purchases. Say I have one month of data for the purchases. I am looking for the interval of time, say 10 mins / 30 mins / hourly, for which 90% of such intervals will contain at least a specified number of sales.  So if I had 100 purchases occur over a 1 month period, and I wanted to find the smallest time interval within which I could count the number of purchases for that interval and have 90% of the counts for the month be >5 purchases, how might I go about determining this time interval?

For example, if I were to divide the data into 15 minute chunks, I might come up with this for the first 90 minutes of the monthly data:

```
Time(minutes)    Purchase count
0-15             1
15-30            0
30-45            6
45-60            2
60-75            4
75-90            3
90-105           1
105-120          5
```

This does not satisfy the criterion: The purchase counts are too small in too many intervals, presumably because the time interval is too small. So I could try 1 hour chunks next:

```
Time(minutes)    Purchase count
0-60              9
60-120           13
```

Now I am satisfying the condition, but perhaps this is not the minimum time chunk: I can probably use a smaller interval than 60 minutes and still have 90% of the counts be above 5.

**Is there way I can do this mathematically or not with brute-force?**

Comment: Unless you have some model for your distribution, you'll have to just do a brute force calculation.  It's possible that your data might be approximated by a Poisson distribution, in which case you could work out some analytic criterion, but without actually having your data I can't say.  At any rate, it'll probably just be easier to plot the 90th percentile as a function of bin width and see where that curve passes through 5.

Comment: @gung I have the exact purchase times for each individual purchase: the data is stored as a record of each individual purchase and the time of purchase. I am using SQL queries to group the purchases into bins of possible time intervals. I have 1 month of data, and approx 500,000 purchases over this 1 month of data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n$ events, here is a $O(n\log(n))$ algorithm that uses simple, common tools.

For simplicity, let's normalize the times so that the start of sales is time $0$ and the end is time $1$.  The normalized times themselves are $$0 \le t_1 \le t_2\le \cdots \le t_n \le 1.$$  Let $n(t)$ be the cumulative distribution through time $t$: $$n(t) = \#\{i\,|\, t_i \le t\}.$$  The number of events in the interval $(t-dt, t]$ of length $dt \ge 0$ therefore is $$\#(t-dt, dt]=n(t) - n(t-dt).$$  Such intervals are wholly included within the range of times $[0,1]$ when $dt \le t \le 1$.  I will interpret the "proportion" of intervals with more than $k$ events as the proportion of this time: $$p(dt,k) = \frac{1}{1-dt}\int_{dt}^1 \mathcal{I}(n(t) - n(t-dt) \ge k) dt.$$  ($\mathcal{I}$ is the binary indicator function.)

For a given count $k \gt 0$ and proportion $1-\alpha$ (such as $\alpha=0.1$ for $90\%$ of the time), the question asks to find the smallest possible $dt$ for which $p(dt, k) \ge 1-\alpha.$  In particular, **$dt$ is a zero of the (discontinuous but monotonic) function $$f(dt) = p(dt, k) - (1-\alpha).$$**  *A good root finder will efficiently discover such as $dt$.*  (If you wish, you may conduct a binary search instead.)

Here are illustrative plots for a synthetic dataset with $n=500,000$ in the course of one month, comparable to the situation posited in the question.

[image: Figures]

Code reproduced below found a solution for $k=1000$ purchases and $\alpha=0.25$; it is $2.72$ hours.

**The top figure** plots $n(t) - n(t-dt)$ for $dt = 2.72\text{ hours}$ = $2.72/(30\times 24)$ $\approx 0.00377\text{ months}.$  The blue horizontal line is located at a count (height) of $k=1000$.  Only the segments at times where the preceding width-$dt$ interval contains $k$ or more purchases are shown. Collectively they comprise exactly $1-\alpha=75\%$ of the month (starting from time $dt$ and ending at time $1$).  *This graph perhaps is even more useful than the answer, because it reveals potentially important details, such as the trend over time.*

**The bottom graph** illustrates this by plotting the total proportion of time against the time interval $dt$ for various values of $k$.  The lower red and yellow curves plot values of $k$ largerthan $1000$ while the higher blue and purle curves plot values of $k$ smaller than $1000$.  The black curve is the plot for $k=1000$.  The value $1-\alpha=0.75$ appears as a black horizontal line.  *The interval where the black curve crosses this line is the solution, $2.72$ hours*.  It should now be visually evident how this problem amounts to finding a crossing (or zero) of a function.

It takes $O(n\log(n))$ time to sort the events, which is the core calculation in computing $n(t)$.  A binary search or decent root finder will take $O(\log(n))$ iterations, each one taking $O(\log(n))$ time for an evaluation (in principle: the `R` implementation is a bit worse, but is simple to implement).

**Here is the `R` code** to produce the synthetic dataset (which oscillates daily and has a slight upward trend) and compute this solution.  `integrate` implements the function $f$ (but divides its values by $n$).  It simply samples the unit interval at a large number of equally spaced points.  `uniroot` is the built-in root finder to find the interval.  It took only $25$ iterations to find a solution precise to $10^{-8}$, requiring less than $0.1$ seconds to complete.  Because these data are so numerous, the solution cannot be appreciably greater than the smallest possible value of $dt$ that works (as the previous plots confirm).

```R
#
# Proportion of time in (dx, 1] that intervals of width `dx` contain at least `y` events.
#
integrate <- function(y, dx, fun, n.points=10001) {
  x <- seq(dx, 1, length.out=n.points)
  mean(f(x) - f(x-dx) >= y * (1-dx))
}
#
# Synthesize the data.
#
n <- 500000
set.seed(17)
dt <- rgamma(n+1, shape=1/10, rate=exp(0:n/n * 1/5)*(1.5 + sin(30*2*pi*0:n/n)))
#
# Normalize them.
#
times <- (cumsum(dt) / sum(dt))[1:n]
#
# Compute the cumulative distribution.
#
f <- ecdf(times)
#
# Specify `k` and `alpha`, then find `dt`.
#
k.0 <- 1000
alpha <- 0.25
fit <- uniroot(function(dx) integrate(k.0/n, dx, f) - (1-alpha), lower=0, upper=1, tol=1e-8)
```